# Status 500 when start Nuxt project by PM2

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, pm2

I have strange issue when I running Nuxt application by PM2 on nginx.
When I start it by "pm2 start" application is working but I have Error 500 when I try to get data from database. When I start application just by "npm start" everything is working fine.
I use "ecosystem.config.js":

```
  module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: 'MyAppName',
        exec_mode: 'cluster',
        instances: 'max',
        script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
        args: 'start'
      }
    ]
  }
```

nginx setup (sites-available/default)

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    index index.html;
    server_name my-domain.com  www.my-domain.com;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
        rewrite ^/_nuxt(/.*) $1 break;
        root /var/www/myApplicationPath;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Request URL: http://my-domain.com/api/cars/?limit=5

The error:

```
{status: 500, message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'limit')", name: "TypeError"}
message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'limit')"
name: "TypeError"
status: 500
```